# Fade in/out (show/hide) divs with side nav links

Tags: jquery, css, html, show-hide

I can't get the divs to show & hide properly, with or without the fade effects. Here is the below code on jsfiddle (for convenience): http://jsfiddle.net/bUjx7/1/

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <header>
        <ul class="sidenav">
            <li><h2><a data-region="nav-1" href="#"><span class="title">About</span></a></h2></li>
            <li><h2><a data-region="nav-2" href="#"><span class="title">Services</span></a></h2></li>
        </ul>
    </header>
    <div id="nav-1" class="infozone"><p>Hello I'm box 1.</p></div>
    <div id="nav-2" class="infozone"><p>Hello I'm box 2.</p></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.infozone{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    height:400px;
    width:800px;
    background-color: #000;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0);
    display:none;
}
```

js:

```
$('.title a').click(function(){
  $('.infozone').fadeOut(550);
  var region = $(this).attr('data-region');    
  $('#' + region).fadeIn(550);
})
```

Comment: Works just fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/bUjx7/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't select use jquery library in your fiddle. And also the selector is not correct, it should be `.sidenav a` instead of `.title a`. Now, it works.
Check it on jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/bUjx7/5/

```
$('.sidenav a').click(function(){
  $('.infozone').fadeOut(550);
  var region = $(this).attr('data-region');    
  $('#' + region).fadeIn(550);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the fade out effect is still being triggered on the element when you try and fade in. Try

```
$('.title a').click(function(){
  var region = $(this).attr('data-region');
  $( 'div' ).hasClass('infozone').not('#' + region).fadeOut(550);    
  $('#' + region).fadeIn(550);
});
```

I have not tested this so please let me know if it works. Basically I am calling the fadeOut on all elements that have the infozone class that are not the desired element that you wish to show.